# Superfish - File not found: sites/all/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js

Tags: 7, navigation

I just downloaded and enabled the latest (dev) version of superfish module, as well as the library... I am getting the following error:

> File not found: sites/all/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js

Should I remove this line from the libraries path:

```
sites/all/libraries/superfish/sftouchscreen.js
```

Or just download a previous (recommended) version of superfish?

Comment: verify that `sftouchscreen.js` file exist in `libraries/superfish` folder.

Comment: Thanks @monymirza

sftouchscreen.js does exist but sfsmallscreen.js doesnt. Where can I get it from?

Comment: @kine456 youre wasting time of us. There are some stuff you should follow, rather than asking silly questions here. I dont think you cant understand the meaning of `File not found`, read something, respect yourself and others as well. 153 questions in 2 month. Also youre answering your own question and marking as the correct answer. Give and take respect buddy. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/12856/kine456

Comment: @Nikhil M, u have got a good analysis about user. these kind of question really waste time. kine456 should read docs about module. So, it can save others time. 153 questions in 2 month, its suspicious..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the [Superfish library](https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal) and extract it to `sites/all/libraries/superfish` (so that the **superfish.js** will be located at http://example.com/sites/all/libraries/superfish/superfish.js)

Comment: Thanks @monymirza

That's exactly what I did, yet the missing file :(

Answer (score 3):

use command for drush user: "drush superfish-plugin"
then it create new libraries folder and contains superfish library.then add your libraries file in config file.it works.

Answer (score 0):

The correct path for `Superfish` is

```
sites/all/libraries/superfish/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/jquery.bgiframe.min.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/superfish.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/supersubs.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/supposition.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/sftouchscreen.js
sites/all/libraries/superfish/sfsmallscreen.js
```

Enter this lines in **Superfish library Path**

Answer (score 0):

Download the `superfish` library from https://github.com/mehrpadin/Superfish-for-Drupal. This includes `sfsmallscreen.js`.